# Bind to single object in viewmodel

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I got this property in my viewmodel:

```
        private PushPinModel selectedPushPinModel;
    public PushPinModel SelectedPushPinModel
    {
        get { return selectedPushPinModel; }
        set
        {
            selectedPushPinModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedPushPinModel);
        }
    }
```

And I want to bind the view to show which one is selected:

```
        <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedPushPinModel}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="91*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="389*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Opacity="0.95" Width="480" Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <Image Width="70" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Icon}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource TextboxLabelStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl >
```

However I can't get it to work. The bindings is not showing in the view and I'm not getting any binding errors. Is it the correct way to bind to a single object?
I much rather having it like this instead of binding directly with {Binding SelectedPushPinModel.Body} which more dirty.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, replaced DataContext on the ContentControl with Content

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPushPinModel}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Thanks to sircodesalot for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedPushPinModel}" />
```

See what that gives you (if anything). Also, check the 'output' window for errors.

This line:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding SelectedPushPinModel}">
```

will only work if the `DataContext` for the ViewModel (Class) has been properly bound higher on the page. If it isn't then the `Label` binding provided above will show blank.

Comment: Yeah the label binding works fine. How do I make it work with the contentcontrol?